# Applying action to a button in one frame makes it apply to whole movieclip in Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movieclip with several layers and frames. Some of those contain buttons. When I click button 1 I want it to go to the next frame. When I click button 2 I want it to go to frame 23. This is the code I'm using for button 1:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, convnext);
function convnext(evt:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    MovieClip(parent).gesprekkencivcen.nextFrame();
}
```

and this is the code for button 2:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, convend1);
function convend1(evt:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    MovieClip(parent).gesprekkencivcen.gotoAndStop(23);
}
```

What happens now is that when I click either of the buttons, or in fact anywhere inside the movieclip (even layers I haven't applied actions to) it executes both functions at the same time so I end up going to frame 24. Can somebody provide an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `this` in both cases refers to the same object, and not to the buttons in particular. Record the names of those buttons as you've named their instances on the timeline, say `button1` and `button2` and write the code employing those names.

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, convnext);
function convnext(evt:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    parent.parent.gesprekkencivcen.nextFrame();
}
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, convend1);
function convend1(evt:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    parent.parent.gesprekkencivcen.gotoAndStop(23);
}
```

With this, however, you will need to update the link to `gesprekkencivcen` in both listeners, as those buttons will have `this` as parent, and their target apparently is not a child of `this`. I have tried to plainly set a call to `parent.parent.gesprekkencivcen`, which might not work.

Comment: When I changed "parent.parent.gesprekkencivcen" to "MovieClip(parent).gesprekkencivcen" it worked fine. Thanks!